# How to edit a specific item in a list in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.4

```
list = ["60", "70", "40", "30", "73", "8"]
```

Here for example, how would i go about

1. taking an item out of the list (Let's say `40` for example)
2. performing an operation on it (let's say `int(40) - 30)`)
3. and then put that item (i.e. `'40'`) back into the list in the position it originally was (3rd)?

The updated list in this case should be:

```
["60", "70", "10", "30", "73", "8"]
```

Comment: What do you mean by `(ItemFromList-30)` ?

Comment: item from the list e.g 40-30

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean this.

```
In [20]: l = ["60", "70", "40", "30", "73", "8"]

In [21]: l[2] = str(int(l[2])-30)

In [22]: l
Out[22]: ['60', '70', '10', '30', '73', '8']
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
In [2]: List=["60", "70", "40", "30", "73", "8"]

In [3]: List[List.index("40")] = str(int(List[List.index("40")]) - 30)

In [4]: List
Out[4]: ['60', '70', '10', '30', '73', '8']
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason for removing it from the list?

```
y =["60", "70", "40", "30", "73", "8"]
x = int(y[2])
x -= 30
y[2] = str(x)
```

This feels like it would be the simplist option

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to replace multiple items, you could do it this way:

```
myList = [str(int(i)-30) if i=="40" else i for i in myList]
```

Comment: This does *not* replace *all items* in the list, but *all items equal to `'40'`*  and *removes* the other ones in `myList`.

Comment: Sorry about my last rude and not very constrictive command. In my opinion the question was how to *edit* specific items in a list, but following your suggestion *all* items *not equal to `'40'`* will not appear in `newList`. So in this case the result is a list containing only *one* item (`["10"]`), rather than the *original list* including the *edited* value (`["60", "70", "10", "30", "73", "8"]`). Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Haha whoops, that's what I get for posting untested code! You're totally right.